# Plotting financial data with matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I saw [this matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.html).

I want to use it for Indian stocks. Now matplotib.finance defines:

```
def fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, date1, date2, cachename=None,dividends=False):
.....
urlFmt = 'http://table.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=%d&b=%d&c=%d&d=%d&e=%d&f=%d&s=%s& y=0&g=%s&ignore=.csv'


    url = urlFmt % (d1[0], d1[1], d1[2],d2[0], d2[1], d2[2], ticker, g)
.....
```

and then does

```
urlopen(url)
```

But the format for getting data from Yahoo India is slightly different. So I went to in.finance.yahoo.com and got the link to historical prices of Reliance Industries as:

```
http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=RELIANCE.NS&a=03&b=1&c=2012&d=02&e=31&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

But now I pop this into a function `indian.py` as:

```
urlFmt='http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&d=%d&e=%d&f=%d&g=d&a=%d&b=%d&c=%d&ignore=.csv'
```

When I run this, I get a `HTTP 404 error`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: as a side note, there is a PR in to drastically change the api of these functions (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1920).  Probably won't make it in till 1.4 though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the order of the variables in your string format don't match up any longer. Using the following `urlFmt` with the original string format expression works:

```
urlFmt = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=%d&b=%d&c=%d&d=%d&e=%d&f=%d&s=%s&g=%s&ignore=.csv'
url = urlFmt % (d1[0], d1[1], d1[2], d2[0], d2[1], d2[2], ticker, g)
```

This will produce the `url` http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=RELIANCE.NS&a=3&b=1&c=2012&d=2&e=31&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv when the variables are set as follows:

```
d1 = [3, 1, 2012]
d2 = [2, 31, 2013]
ticker = 'RELIANCE.NS'
g = 'd'
```